# CSS3 animation not working in IE11 and Microsoft Edge

Tags: css, animation, internet-explorer-11, microsoft-edge

This animation is working perfectly fine in chrome, firefox and opera.
But it is not working in IE11 and Microsoft Edge. Can someone point out why it is not working and how can I make it work?

https://jsfiddle.net/0suvxsL3/1/

Code is already using `vendor prefixes`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I solved the problem. The problem is with `calc()`. It does not work inside keyframes in IE and Edge. This can be solved by chaining multiple `translateX()` to construct the expression inside `calc()`.

**For example:**

`left: calc(100vw - 20px)` is same as

`left: translateX(100vw) translateX(-20px)`

[Updated jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0suvxsL3/2/)